# Trouble with VBA Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Tags: excel, vba, paste

thanks for any support in advance!

I'm having an issue copying and pasting data from a CSV file to a table in excel.

I have a macro that opens a CSV file, reads all the ID's in the first column and compares it with ID's a table in the main workbook. The macro then identifies new ID's and copies the relevant data to the main workbook adding rows to the bottom of a table.

My problem is that in the CSV file the date column is pre-formatted to read as 29/03/2020 (UK format) however when the data is pasted into the table in the main workbook the dates are pasted in US format where possible.

Is there a way I can force the paste operation to treat all the data as text which I can then format after?

```
Sub LookupIDandPaste(rg As Range, rgCompare As Range, dict As Dictionary, resultType As eResultType, OpenBook As Workbook)
'lookup row number in rgCompare of transaction ID's not already listed in rgBase (identified in sub MainCompare)

    Dim key As Variant
    Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim newRow As Range
    Dim newTableRowNum As Long
    Dim newTableCellRange As Range
    'Dim monzoTransFirstCol As String
    'Set monzoTransFirstCol

        For Each key In dict

        rowNum = Application.Match(key, rgCompare, 0) + 1 'row number in rgCompare of new item (plus 1 to account for header row)
        Set newRow = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & rowNum & ":P" & rowNum)

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Transactions (Monzo)").ListObjects("MonzoTransactions").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True

        newTableRowNum = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Transactions (Monzo)").ListObjects("MonzoTransactions").ListRows.Count + 2
        Set newTableCellRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Transactions (Monzo)").Range("Q" & newTableRowNum) 'cell in table

        newRow.Copy
        newTableCellRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'paste operation

    Next key

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, please replacing of:

```
newRow.Copy
newTableCellRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

with

```
With newTableCellRange.Resize(newRow.Rows.Count, newRow.Columns.Count)
      .NumberFormat = "@"
      .value = newRow.value
End With
```

Comment: @NathanG: Glad I could help!